# How does one collect sql rows in Groovy

Tags: mysql, sql, groovy

I am trying to make a stream `collect` on my SQL rowset within a groovy script, however the output is an empty array. Calling print within the closure works.

Any ideas on how I can processes all the rows without having to consume them in the first closure and without referencing out-of-scope variables?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "login", "password", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

// Display databases
println "Databases: "
println sql.eachRow("SHOW databases") {row -> "${row[0]}"}.collect()
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html). None of `eachRow` methods returns a collection.

Maybe try:

```
println sql.rows("SHOW databases").collect { row -> "${row[0]}" }
```